# "Our end" vs. "our side"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, nouns, email

Which is correct when writing emails?

> 1. Everything is fine at **our/your end**.
> 2. Everything is fine at **our/your side**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Between those two sets of choices specifically, the first is correct.

However, using 'our side'/'your side' isn't the part that's wrong in the second examples, it's the preposition: you can be **at** an end, but you are **on** a side.  So you could say "Everything is fine on our side."

Comment: To me there is also a very slight connotative difference.  "our side" vs "your side" COULD imply competition/opponents, whereas "our end"/"your end" doesn't.