# "On the other end / side" of the phone line

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, telephone

What's the proper way to reference somebody who're you talking with by a peer-to-peer phone line, usually if you don't know who's there exactly?

Russian language, for example, has the idiom

```
(они) на другом конца провода
```

which is literally

```
(they, who appear to be) on the other end of the [phone] wire
```

Note that it is in plural and it can be used even for wireless (i.e. cell) phones. What is the proper way to say that in English? I've stumbled a couple of times to usage "(at/on) the other end", "(at/on) the other side" in some texts, but I'm not sure that they're authentic, correct and relate to precisely what I'm talking about. I've checked the dictionaries, but I couldn't find anything relevant.

Possibly related, but still doesn't give the exact answer on telephone line specific case:

- ["Our end" vs. "our side"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63594/our-end-vs-our-side)

Definitely not related:

- ["On the one/other hand" vs. "on the one/other side"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73179/on-the-one-other-hand-vs-on-the-one-other-side)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common idea among native English speakers is that a conversation over a distance has "ends," with each participant at one end of the connection. I would bet that this way of thinking came along with the advent of the telephone (although I can't substantiate that at this time).

As a result, someone with whom you are communicating by phone or email would be described as "the person on the other end."

Similarly, a nice thing to ask in a conversation with your friend could be, "How are things on your end, Bill?" which is pretty much the same as "How are you doing?"

Comment: It may be worth noting that a conversation can have any number of "ends," such as when you are on a conference call or multi-party email.

Answer (score 1):

In British English, at least, it would be *on the other end (of the line)*.

Answer (score 1):

"On the other side" suggests that you and the other party are in two different territories, separated by a border or barrier. "On the other end" connotes a real or virtual line or conduit that stretches between you and the other party, such as a road or a network connection. Because the latter is a much better description of a telephone call than the former is, we say "on the other end."

Comment: And even if you're video-chatting -- where the interface (the screen) is much more similar to a vertical barrier than with a traditional phone -- one would still say "on the other *end*".